# JPA Criteria api with CONTAINS function

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to crete Criteria API query with CONTAINS function(MS SQL):

select * from com.t_person where contains(last_name,'xxx')

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> cq = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> root = cq.from(Person.class);

Expression<Boolean> function = cb.function("CONTAINS", Boolean.class, 
root.<String>get("lastName"),cb.parameter(String.class, "containsCondition"));
cq.where(function);
TypedQuery<Person> query = em.createQuery(cq);
query.setParameter("containsCondition", lastName);
return query.getResultList();
```

But getting exception:
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node:

Any help?

Comment: What version of hibernate you are using?

Comment: Version bundled with JBOSS. Accually not using Hibernate API just JPA.

Comment: have you found a solution to remove acentuate char?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to stick with using `CONTAINS`, it should be something like this:

```
//Get criteria builder
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
//Create the CriteriaQuery for Person object
CriteriaQuery<Person> query = cb.createQuery(Person.class);

//From clause
Root<Person> personRoot = query.from(Person.class);

//Where clause
query.where(
    cb.function(
        "CONTAINS", Boolean.class, 
        //assuming 'lastName' is the property on the Person Java object that is mapped to the last_name column on the Person table.
        personRoot.<String>get("lastName"), 
        //Add a named parameter called containsCondition
        cb.parameter(String.class, "containsCondition")));

TypedQuery<Person> tq = em.createQuery(query);
tq.setParameter("containsCondition", "%näh%");
List<Person> people = tq.getResultList();
```

It seems like some of your code is missing from your question so I'm making a few assumptions in this snippet.

Comment: I got QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: ( near line 1, column 109 [select generatedAlias0 from sk.insdata.cbn.business.client.entities.Person as generatedAlias0 where CONTAINS(generatedAlias0.lastName, :param0)]

Comment: @petersaly Check my edit... I think you actually need a cb.equal in there as well.

Comment: That i tried at first: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Incorrect syntax near '='

Comment: If you just run that query on your database: `select generatedAlias0 from sk.insdata.cbn.business.client.entities.Person as generatedAlias0 where CONTAINS(generatedAlias0.lastName, :param0)` does it work?

Comment: yes running native query works: select * from com.t_person where contains(last_name,'%saly%')

Comment: Hmm, found this https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3992. Looks like it could be a Hibernate bug.

Comment: Thanks for help. I will watch that issue.

Answer (score 6):

You could try using the CriteriaBuilder [like](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#like%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29) function instead of the `CONTAINS` function:

```
//Get criteria builder
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
//Create the CriteriaQuery for Person object
CriteriaQuery<Person> query = cb.createQuery(Person.class);

//From clause
Root<Person> personRoot = query.from(Person.class);

//Where clause
query.where(
    //Like predicate
    cb.like(
        //assuming 'lastName' is the property on the Person Java object that is mapped to the last_name column on the Person table.
        personRoot.<String>get("lastName"),
        //Add a named parameter called likeCondition
        cb.parameter(String.class, "likeCondition")));

TypedQuery<Person> tq = em.createQuery(query);
tq.setParameter("likeCondition", "%Doe%");
List<Person> people = tq.getResultList();
```

This should result in a query similar to:

```
select p from PERSON p where p.last_name like '%Doe%';
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to achieve to be able do advanced searches like accent insensitive search (näh - will find - nah).

Comment: From my experience CriteriaBulider.like is very limited. It only supports surrounding wildcards, i.e: %doe% but not %doe