# JPA Criteria API checking if an association collection is a subset of another collection

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables: `job` and `language`. The relationship between these two tables is m:n, which means a job may require many languages and a language can be required by many jobs. So I have to create a third table called `job_language` to represent this relationship, it just contains two column `job_id` (which is an integer) and `language_code` (such as `'eng'` for English or `'jap'` for Japanese, etc.). The database i'm using is MySQL.

Now I have to create a REST service using Spring Data JPA to get all jobs that require a set of languages which is a subset of another set of languages from user's inputs. For example, suppose I have 3 jobs with the values in table `job_language` like below:

```
--------------------------
| job_id | language_code |
--------------------------
| 1      | 'eng'         |
--------------------------
| 2      | 'eng'         |
--------------------------
| 2      | 'vie'         |
--------------------------
| 3      | 'jap'         |
--------------------------
| 3      | 'eng'         |
--------------------------
| 3      | 'vie'         |
--------------------------
```

Now user wants to find jobs that require `('eng', 'vie')` (this is a list of `language_code` created from user's input), the query should return two jobs: job with `job_id = 1` and job with `job_id = 2`.

These are my entity classes:

```
@Entity
public class Job {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "job_language", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "job_id", nullable = false) },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "language_code", nullable = false) })
    private List<Language> languages;

    // getters and setters here...
}

@Entity
public class Language { 
    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "char", length = 3)
    private String code;

    @Column(length = 100)
    private String name;

    // getters and setters...
}
```

I have a MySQL query that does exactly this but since JPQL does not allow left joining two unrelated tables, I cannot find a solution using JPA Criteria API. Any suggestions?

This is my working query:

```
select jl1.job_id
from job_language jl1 left join job_language jl2 on jl1.job_id = jl2.job_id and jl1.language_code = jl2.language_code and jl2.language_code in ('eng', 'vie')
group by jl1.job_id
having count(jl1.language_code) = count(jl2.language_code);
```

Comment: please, see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488351/jpa-criteria-api-with-contains-function

Comment: @MatiasCaamaño no it won't help, that question is about checking if a string is contained in another string but mine is about checking if a association collection is a subset of another collection, maybe i'm not clear in my question, let me edit it and please take a look later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your query as a native SQL query with a Spring Data repository.  As an example:

```
public interface JobRepository extends JobRepository<Job, Long> {
  @Query(nativeQuery = true
      , value = "SELECT "
              + "  * "
              + "FROM"
              + "  job "
              + "WHERE "
              + "  id IN "
              + "  ( "
              + "  SELECT "
              + "    jl1.job_id "
              + "  FROM "
              + "    job_language jl1 "
              + "  LEFT JOIN "
              + "    job_language jl2 "
              + "  ON "
              + "    jl1.job_id = jl2.job_id "
              + "  AND jl1.language_code = jl2.language_code "
              + "  AND jl2.language_code IN ?1 "
              + "  GROUP BY "
              + "    jl1.job_id "
              + "  HAVING "
              + "    COUNT(jl1.language_code) = COUNT(jl2.language_code) "
              + "  )")
  List<Job> findAllByLanguageCodes(String... languageCodes);
}
```

The only criterion for using native queries is that Spring Data should be able to translate the return value(s) of a native query into the return type of the annotated method.  We take advantage of this by putting a `SELECT * FROM job` at the top of the query, which allows Spring Data JPA to handle the results nicely since `job` is mapped to a JPA entity (even if `job_location`, which really drives the query, is not).

See a working example [here](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-jpa-hibernate/blob/master/src/test/java/org/example/data/hiring/HiringTest.java).

Comment: Thank you. Spring Data JPA doesn't allow paging with native query, and this is the reason why I gave up using native query, but now i know there are 'limit' and 'offset' keywords in MySQL, native query is the solution to my problem. Thanks for suggesting me to use native query, so I could look at it again :).

Comment: Paged queries use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` so you are on the right track.